# Does the Standard Define Common Bases?

Tags: c++, decimal, standards, radix, strtol

[`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), for example, takes a base as its last argument

I find passing in the magic number `10` in all over my code to be unappealing. Is the decimal base already defined somewhere in the standard?

Comment: `strtol` is a C function, why C++ would define something for it?

Comment: @Slava Perhaps because it's part of the C++ standard library by inclusion.

Comment: @Slava I know that I'm out of my depth trying to argue with you on anything C++ related, but I'd like to respectfully point out that this seems to be the most natural way provided by the standard for extracting a number from a `char*`.

Comment: Work around the problem using the newer C++11 functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: @NathanOliver I find the construction of a `string` undesirable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any standard base definition for use with `strtol`. However, there are alternative conversion functions, which have `10` as the default argument for base, such as [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which works on `std::string`s, and the new [`std::from_chars`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) which works on `const char*`s.

Answer (score 1):

> I find passing in the magic number 10 in all over my code to be unappealing.

You can use `0` for `base` and let the implementation deduce the base.

```
auto v1 = strtol("101", nullptr, 0); // base is deduced to be 10
auto v2 = strtol("078", nullptr, 0); // base is deduced to be 8
auto v3 = strtol("0xF09", nullptr, 0); // base is deduced to be 16
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no decimal base default value defined for `strtol`. You can create your own proxy function, like :

```
long int strtolBase10(const char *nptr, char **endptr)
{
  return strtol(nptr, endptr, 10);
}
```

It's worth noting that if you use the special value `0` as the base parameter, strtol will parse as decimal unless the string starts with '0x' or '0X' (it will parse in base 16) or starts with a '0' (it will parse in base 8).